# Submitting form with serialize() - how to avoid the placeholder text?

Tags: html, jquery, placeholder

Im submitting my form and saving the data with an $.ajax `$("#formName").serialize()` post call.

My issue is that the placeholder text is submitted with the serialize() action.

I have a function that resets the placeholder value to "" in case placeholder == placeholder - however im not sure how to combine that with my ajax - serialize() - call.

[Fiddle of my setup here](http://jsfiddle.net/xUcXs/1/)

Any suggestions?

Comment: you don't have button in your fiddle..check it out

Answer (score 0):

Use required attribute.
Your form will be submitted only when some value is inserted.
i.e. 
`<input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" name="fieldEmail" required="required">`

Comment: Hi Hiral - thanks for the suggestion. Lets say I have two additional input fields, both with placeholder text and these fields are optional - then I guess this technique wouldn't work so well